# Thymeleaf show <TR> based in conditions

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I want to show a  only if only 1 object is not null, but with the code beneath. In fact it is working but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Invalid location of tag (div).
    - No end tag (</div>).
```

the template:

```
<div  th:if="${currentSkills != null}">
   <tr ><!-- Data File -->
      <td class="col_id">E000</td><!-- ID -->
      <td class="col_name">TD0000 EVB</td><!-- NAME -->
      <td class="col_name">Test Device</td><!-- NAME -->
      <td class="col_battery"><!-- BATTERY -->
    <div class="progressBar" id="max14"><div>
</div></div><!-- bar % (Change ID maxnumber)-->
     </td>
     <td class="col_temp">0ºC / 0ºF </td><!-- TEMP. -->
     <td class="col_last_event">Fri, 17 Mar 2017 10:50:44 GMT+01:00</td><!-- LAST EVENT -->
     <td class="col_signal">149 dBm.</td><!-- SIGNAL -->
     <td class="col_state"></td><!-- STATE -->
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix all of the annotated errors by removing the `<div>` and instead placing the `th:if` directly on the `<tr>`.

```
<tr th:if="${currentSkills != null}"><!-- Data File -->
  <td class="col_id">E000</td><!-- ID -->
  <td class="col_name">TD0000 EVB</td><!-- NAME -->
  <td class="col_name">Test Device</td><!-- NAME -->
  <td class="col_battery"><!-- BATTERY -->
    <div class="progressBar" id="max14"><div>
    </div></div><!-- bar % (Change ID maxnumber)-->
  </td>
  <td class="col_temp">0ºC / 0ºF </td><!-- TEMP. -->
  <td class="col_last_event">Fri, 17 Mar 2017 10:50:44 GMT+01:00</td><!-- LAST EVENT -->
  <td class="col_signal">149 dBm.</td><!-- SIGNAL -->
  <td class="col_state"></td><!-- STATE -->
</tr>
```